# How to select the 3rd row from a table in mysql?

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I want to select the 3rd row from the mysql table.

Note: the table is updated frequently. How to select always the 3rd row from column one.

[image]

Comment: There is no such thing as the "third row" in a relational table. Rows in a table are ***NOT*** sorted. Only if you specify an `order by` you can talk about "the third row".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
   SELECT *
   FROM emps
   ORDER BY empid
   LIMIT 3
) AS T
ORDER BY empid DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 3):

The offset of LIMIT clause is Zero based. Try this:

```
   SELECT *
   FROM emps
   ORDER BY empid
   LIMIT 2, 1
```

**[SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e92cc7/1)**

Answer (score 2):

Try this::

```
Select * from tableA order by empid desc limit 3,1
```